# How to do animated switcher with slivers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

So I have a CustomScrollView with a `SliverAppBar(floating: true, snap: true)`, a `SliverPersistentHeader(pinned: true)` a `SliverList`.

What I am trying to do is to click a button in the header and just pop a widget in the space taken by the `SliverPersistentHeade` and `SliverList`. I tried putting them inside a `nestedScrollView` and nesting `SliverPersistentHeader` and `SliverList` inside another scrollView but since the `SliverAppBar` and `SliverPersistentHeader` are not together it messes up the supposed effect when it(`SliverAppBar`) snaps up and off.

**Why do I need it like that**: I want to perform some animations with the elements in the appBar as the lower part transitions between the two pages kinda like [animtions shared axis package](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages/animations#shared-axis)

problems

- keep the persistantHeader on the first page
- keep the snap floating appbar feature
- transition the lower part

**Note:** Answers don't necessary need to depend on slivers. a possible way to achieve that will do

My code at the moment looks roughly like this

```
CustomScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            floating: true,
            snap: true,
            titleSpacing: 0,
            elevation: 4,
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10),
                    child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: LeadingButton(
                    color: lightShadeColor,
                    icon: Icons.qr_code_scanner_rounded,
                    iconColor: darkColor,
                    size: 37, // btnShadow: false
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: PersistentHeader(
                    widget: Row(
                      // Format this to meet your need
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text('data'),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  pinned: true,
                ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('index $index'),
              );
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: I would also love to see a solution for this. But perhaps we just have to dig into the source code ans find a solution our selves. 

Comment: Have you found a solution to that problem?